# How can I apply text attributes to text in a list in CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to write the CSS to color the text (bullets AND text) of an HTML list.

I have found the list bullet attributes, but nothing to address the text in the list. How and where should I apply the text styles to the list itself?

I've tried surrounding the list--everthing between the [UL] and [/UL] tags with [DIV][/DIV] (brackets used to get by the board's code interpreter)

but, this is not correct and only renders properly in some browsers.

Comment: li { color: pink; } ????

Comment: Show us your HTML markup and CSS code.

Comment: Well, I got it working in all the browsers I'm testing now, just trying to construct a reply for you. But, I still don't think this is properly coded.
Have a look and see if this is right...I've never had to close a LI tag before...not sure you're supposed to. But, it's the only way to get it working right.

`code`
<DIV>
<UL>
<SPAN class=bigblue>
<LI>Lightweight EVA</LI></SPAN> 
<SPAN class=bigblue>
<LI>Easy to adjust... heat, cut, or grind </LI></SPAN>
</UL>
</DIV>

Comment: Wrapping `<li>` elements in a `<span>` is not technically correct since the `li` elements are block level and `span`'s are inline, so not good.  It is better to put the `span` in the `li` tag, as shown in my post.

Comment: that's what I understood, as well. Maybe what I'm asking is simply not possible by the CSS book. I'm just looking for a way to define multiple UL styles. maybe there's an acceptable outside-the-rules way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of doing it is as follows:

Wrap your text in an inline element, for example, `<span>`:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>first</span></li>
    <li><span>second</span></li>
    <li><span>third</span></li>
</ul>
```

And apply the following CSS:

```
ul li {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 2.0em;
}
ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

The rule for `ul li` applies the color to both the list marker and the list text.

The rule for `ul li span` is more specific and applies a new color only to the text in the `span` element.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ALAFP/)

Comment: that works fine if I want to make every list colored (inclusive of bullets). but, I need to have different styles (colors) of lists. How would I define multiple `code` ul li {

Comment: For each `ul`, add a class (example, "style1") and then create a CSS rule according to the colors that you need, for example, `ul.style1 li` and then `ul.style1 li span`.  I added a second example in the fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: awesome. got it. i was not assigning class at the UL, but trying to create the DIV outside of it. that was my issue. many thanks.

Comment: Great! You were getting there but you just needed a clear demonstration.  Don't forget to accept and up vote the answer.  Good luck with the project!